# Count the number of value based on range across multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I want to calculate the sum based on range is `0-20`, `21-40`, `41-60`, `61-80`, `81-100`.

Example dataset:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "No  Eng  Chi  Art  Sci 
1  15 10 87 99 
2  75 51 89 81 
3  91 56 82 73 
4  43 10 89 64 
5  67 91 18 83 
6  12 70 65 82 
7  95 83 91 77
8  23 82 47 91
9  58 59 62 73", header = TRUE)
```

Desired Output:

```r
       Eng Chi Art Sci
0-20     2   2   1   0
21-40    1   0   0   0
41-60    2   3   1   0
61-80    2   1   2   4
81-100   2   3   5   5
```

Thanks.

my real data like:

```
structure(list(NO = 1:20, Eng = c(1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.005114, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05), Chi = c(1e-05, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.001443, 1e-05, 0.020056, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 0.015733), Art = c(0.818886, 0.64295, 0.943425, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 0.776237, 0.645814, 0.456605, 1e-05, 0.819518, 0.966289, 
0.879817, 0.873742, 0.885072, 0.83168, 0.747507, 0.954986, 0.756705, 
0.782298, 0.755385), Sci = c(1e-05, 0.007769, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.002237, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.024473, 1e-05)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55db35af6b10>)
```

And I have tried code from answer

```
breaks <- seq(0, 1, 0.2)
labels <- paste0(breaks[-length(breaks)], "-", breaks[-1])

transform(stack(tmp1[-1]), values = cut(values, breaks, labels, include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
  table()
```

But I got error like `Error in cut.default(values, breaks, labels, include.lowest = TRUE) :  'x' must be numeric`

```
> str(tmp1)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  20 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ NO : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Eng: num  1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 ...
 $ Chi: num  1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 1e-05 ...
 $ Art: num  0.81889 0.64295 0.94342 0.00001 0.00001 ...
 $ Sci: num  0.00001 0.00777 0.00001 0.00001 0.00001 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stack` + `cut` + `table`. Breaks are defined in `br`, and custom labels in `lbl`:

```r
br = seq(0, 100, 20)
lbl = paste0(c(0, tail(head(br + 1, -1), -1)), "-", tail(br, -1))
transform(stack(df[-1]), values = cut(values, br, lbl, include.lowest = TRUE)) |>
  table()

        ind
values   Eng Chi Art Sci
  0-20     2   2   1   0
  21-40    1   0   0   0
  41-60    2   3   1   0
  61-80    2   1   2   4
  81-100   2   3   5   5
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I got error in my real data like ```Error in cut.default(values, breaks, labels, include.lowest = TRUE) : 
  'x' must be numeric```, did I miss something? I update my real datafame.

Comment: It's probably because `values` is not numeric in your real data, you can convert first: `as.numeric(values)`

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with the new data set, I get the same result. The best would be to clean your environment or restart R and try again.

Comment: I found the where problem is ```as.data.frame()``` ,can't work at data.table.After change to df it's work! Thanks a million.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cut()` + `table()`:

```r
tab <- sapply(df[-1], \(x) table(cut(x, seq(0, 100, 20), include.lowest = TRUE)))
tab
#          Eng Chi Art Sci
# [0,20]     2   2   1   0
# (20,40]    1   0   0   0
# (40,60]    2   3   1   0
# (60,80]    2   1   2   4
# (80,100]   2   3   5   5
```

- Re-label

```r
row.names(tab) <- sub(".(\\d+),(\\d+).", "\\1-\\2", row.names(tab))
tab
#        Eng Chi Art Sci
# 0-20     2   2   1   0
# 20-40    1   0   0   0
# 40-60    2   3   1   0
# 60-80    2   1   2   4
# 80-100   2   3   5   5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `tabulate` in `vapply`.

```
vapply(df, \(x) tabulate(as.integer(cut(x, seq(0, 100, 20), include.lowest = TRUE))), integer(5))
#      Eng Chi Art Sci
# [1,]   2   2   1   0
# [2,]   1   0   0   0
# [3,]   2   3   1   0
# [4,]   2   1   2   4
# [5,]   2   3   5   5
```

Or `tabulate` in `tapply`

```
as.integer(cut(as.matrix(df), seq.int(0, 100, 20), include.lowest=TRUE)) |>
    tapply(gl(ncol(df), nrow(df)), tabulate) |> simplify2array()
#      1 2 3 4
# [1,] 2 2 1 0
# [2,] 1 0 0 0
# [3,] 2 3 1 0
# [4,] 2 1 2 4
# [5,] 2 3 5 5
```

Or using `matrixStats::colTabulates`.

```
as.integer(cut(as.matrix(df[-1]), seq.int(0, 100, 20), include.lowest=TRUE)) |>
  `dim<-`(dim(df[-1])) |> matrixStats::colTabulates()
#      1 2 3 4 5
# [1,] 2 1 2 2 2
# [2,] 2 0 3 1 3
# [3,] 1 0 1 2 5
# [4,] 0 0 0 4 5
```

(Note, that the result is transposed, append a `|> t()` to transpose again, if needed.)

### Benchmark

Actually the `tabulate` looked faster not to loop over columns, but the `vapply` combined with `tabulate` turned out to be fastest with larger datasets.

#### 1,000 rows

```
Unit: microseconds
         expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 colTabulates  744.401  758.4825  882.0845  771.8360  799.3205  7421.496   100
       sapply 1288.152 1311.6170 1374.1736 1324.1255 1357.8350  1764.702   100
       vapply 1254.083 1275.8640 1534.6101 1286.4790 1317.2115 19991.561   100
      vapply2  968.165  982.7900 1109.2416  995.0465 1031.2435  5314.813   100
       tapply  769.434  782.0720  875.8199  793.7405  811.2995  2763.518   100
```

#### 100,000 rows

```
Unit: milliseconds
         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 colTabulates 38.03267 39.19212 44.50995 44.07142 46.43025 82.15103   100
       sapply 34.02919 34.91995 39.31347 39.80455 41.89220 54.12442   100
       vapply 34.06275 34.83629 38.70414 37.68597 41.14927 75.31959   100
      vapply2 25.63094 26.32763 30.13183 27.90852 32.20849 70.45803   100
       tapply 40.48319 40.96569 46.30377 43.81594 48.73864 83.09135   100
```

#### 1,000,000 rows

```
Unit: milliseconds
         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 colTabulates 428.7724 510.4364 580.4688 564.0340 630.4696 964.2294   100
       sapply 430.3531 445.7027 497.9471 494.2131 531.5908 698.2996   100
       vapply 430.3486 481.9096 510.4443 497.1550 548.9843 824.3819   100
      vapply2 296.0403 351.9058 377.3302 358.6291 405.4088 572.0429   100
       tapply 455.1042 567.1265 633.4047 597.2952 707.1524 872.6654   100
```

*Code:*

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  colTabulates=as.integer(cut(as.matrix(df), seq.int(0, 100, 20), include.lowest=TRUE)) |>
    `dim<-`(dim(df)) |> matrixStats::colTabulates(),
  sapply=sapply(df, \(x) table(cut(x, seq(0, 100, 20), include.lowest = TRUE))),
  vapply=vapply(df, \(x) table(cut(x, seq(0, 100, 20), include.lowest = TRUE)), integer(5)),
  vapply2=vapply(df, \(x) tabulate(as.integer(cut(x, seq(0, 100, 20), include.lowest = TRUE))), integer(5)),
  tapply=as.integer(cut(as.matrix(df), seq.int(0, 100, 20), include.lowest=TRUE)) |>
    tapply(gl(ncol(df), nrow(df)), tabulate) |> simplify2array()
)

Rscript --vanilla coltabs_issue.R
```